# Drive Stepper Motor using parallel Port

Tags: driver, stepper-motor, parallel-port

I'm having a little difficulty to drive this kind of motors using parallel port. Have googled loads of tutorials but unfortunately couldn't found any color codes or types of motors I have. I cannot even order or get Stepper Motor Driver (e.g., Arduino) in my region. So looking for creating my own.

These are the motors:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Off-the-shelf stepper motor boards are about 3 USD from on-line retailers. Can you buy from eBay, or common electronics distributers, or are you limited to very simple components from a local store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume each motor has four wires?  If so, it seems you have a pair of bipolar stepper motors.  You will need a dual H bridge motor driver for each of them.

You'll need to use a multimeter to figure out how the wires map to the coils.  All you need to do is figure out which pairs of wires are connected by coils.  It doesn't matter which coil is which or what polarity is correct, swapping the coils or swapping the polarity of one coil will just change which direction the motor rotates.

You cannot drive the motors directly from your parallel port, unfortunately.  It can't drive enough current.  You're going to have to build or buy a motor controller.  The driver has to be able to drive both coils in both directions, so you need what is called a 'dual H bridge' controller.  This type of controller has a power transistor to power and another one to ground on each of the four wires.  There are monolithic chips that have all of this internally - just connect power, connect the motor, and provide step and direction control inputs.  However, you may not be able to get your hands on one of these.  In this case, you're going to have to cobble something together, likely out of some NPN/PNP or MOSFET power transistors and a handful of 7400 series glue logic.  Simplest method would probably be to control each half H bridge separately.  Use an inverter with each half H bridge so a '1' input will pull the output high while a '0' input will pull the output low.  Then wire all four half H bridges to the parallel port, and drive them like so: 01 01, 01 10, 10 10, 10 01, 01 01, etc.  Each pair corresponds to the half H bridges connected to one coil.  Each transition will cause the motor to take one step.  Reverse the order to run the motor in the other direction.